# navigation in c++ program using CEDET in emacs

Tags: emacs, tags, navigation, cedet

I want to use emacs for more efficient c++ programming. However, I'm a beginner in using this editor. I started with CEDET. Now I have a simple question concerning jumping to function definitions:

E.g., when I include fstream header an use the function "void open(...)" I can place the cursor on this function and get the correct info about the location and usage of "open()". Now, what do I have to do (e.g. concerning the tag-ing) to use "navigate" to jump to the file containing the definition of "open"?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I dont use either CEDET or C++. People may like to see your configuration for CEDET, so that they can suggest solutions. BTW did you see this file? its a sample for configuring CPP projects. https://github.com/emacsmirror/cedet/blob/master/lisp/cedet/ede/cpp-root.el

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to jump from a function invocation to the definition of that function, you're probably thinking of the `tags` functionality. Have you looked at [the EmacsWiki page about etags](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags) to see if that's what you're after?  There's also more information in [emacs manual section about tags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html#Tags).